# Change product description based on variant in Shopify

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

I want to be able to change product description based on variant name.  I am following the tutorial here ==> https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/demo-change-description-in-product-with-different-variants-296509

I modified the code a bit in order to use variant.option1 instead of variant.id

Seems like I have no luck as the description is not changing.  Option 1 has "Unisex Tee" and "Women's Tee"

Below is the code:

```
<p class="description" id="Unisex Tee">Unisex Tee</p>
<p class="description" id="Women's Tee" style="display: none;">Women's Tee</p>

// selectCallback is the callback name in Timber
var selectCallback = function(variant, selector) {

   // Simply toggle on/off the panel according to the variant selected
    $('.description').css('display', 'none');
    $('#' + variant.option1).css('display', 'block');
// rest of the Timber code
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am not really good with JS.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code back to use the variant IDs. The `option1` property of the `variant` object is not guaranteed to provide you valid `id` names, as is what is happening in your case. For instance, spaces are not allowed in `id` attributes and neither is the single quote. Read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) for more details. This is why the author of that post was using variant ID. It is a unique identifier and it is also a valid `id` for HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="a">
<ul class="ptabs">
<li><a href="#tab-1">Overview</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-2">Details</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-3">Dimensions</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab-1">
<p><span face="Raleway,sans-serif" color="black" style="color: black; font-family: Raleway,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><br />Overview set of 6</span></p>
</div>
<div id="tab-2">
<p><span face="Raleway,sans-serif" color="black" style="color: black; font-family: Raleway,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">Details set of 6</span></p>
</div>
<div id="tab-3">
<p><span face="Raleway,sans-serif" color="black" style="color: black; font-family: Raleway,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">Dimensions of set of 6</span></p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="b">
<ul class="ptabs">
<li><a href="#tab-4">Overview</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-5">Details</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-6">Dimensions</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab-4">
<p><span face="Raleway,sans-serif" color="black" style="color: black; font-family: Raleway,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><br />Overview set of 12</span></p>
</div>
<div id="tab-5">
<p><span face="Raleway,sans-serif" color="black" style="color: black; font-family: Raleway,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">Details set of 12</span></p>
</div>
<div id="tab-6">
<p><span face="Raleway,sans-serif" color="black" style="color: black; font-family: Raleway,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">Dimensions of set of 12</span></p>
</div>
</div>
<style><!--
#a ,#b {display:none;}
--></style>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
       var s = document.getElementById('product-variants-4452185735-option-0');
var item1 = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;

if (item1 == "Set of 6") {
   document.getElementById('a').style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('b').style.display="none";
}
else if (item1 == "Set of 12") {

   document.getElementById('a').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('b').style.display="block";
}
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some context around your source-code.
Code-only answers are difficult to understand.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--First of all variants Must be defined in shopify backend.then you can see handler name by inspecting element in browser.jquery library files required. -->




    <!--start-->
            <div id="a" style="display: none;">
            <ul class="ptabs">
            <li><a href="#tab-1" class="active">Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-2" class="">Details</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tab-1" style="display: block;">
            <p>tab 1 content</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tab-2" style="display: none;">
            <p>tab 2 content</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <!--end First tab Content Div-->

            <!--start-->
            <div id="b" style="display: block;">
            <ul class="ptabs">
            <li><a href="#tab-1" class="active">Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-2" class="">Details</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tab-1" style="display: block;">
            <p>tab 1 content</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tab-2" style="display: none;">
            <p>tab 2 content</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <!--end Second  tab Content Div-->

            <style>#a ,#b {display:none;}</style>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select").change(function(){
              var select = document.querySelector("select"); //Select element selected
        var get_Handler_Name = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value; //Get selected option handler name 

        //checks whether selected option is "handler_1"
        if (get_Handler_Name == "handler_1") {
           document.getElementById('a').style.display="block";
            document.getElementById('b').style.display="none";
        }

        //checks whether selected option is "handler_2"
        else if (get_Handler_Name == "handler_2") {

           document.getElementById('a').style.display="none";
            document.getElementById('b').style.display="block";
        }
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: get variant id by inspect element i browser..... go to Image_link( https://ibb.co/g6y6Ev )